# Sums of Golden Ratio Powers

Tags: golden-ratio

I had a question regarding the following sum. Let $\phi$ be the golden ratio and $N$ be an even integer.

\begin{array}{lcl} 
\sum_{n=1}^N (-\phi)^n & = & -\phi + (-\phi)^2 + (-\phi)^3 + \ldots + (-\phi)^N \\
& = & (\phi^2 - \phi) + (\phi^4 - \phi^3) + (\phi^6 - \phi^5) + \ldots + (\phi^N - \phi^{N-1}) \\
&=& \kern 1.5pc 1 \kern 1.16pc + \kern 1.5pc \phi^2 \kern 1.05pc + \kern 1.5pc \phi^4 \kern 1.01pc + \ldots + \kern 1.5pc \phi^{N-2}
\end{array}

with $\frac{N}{2}$ terms in the last equation's rhs. I rewrite that as (according to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7BN%2F2%20-%201%7D%20%28golden%20ratio%29%5E%282*n%29))

\begin{array}{lcl}
\sum_{n=0}^{N/2 - 1} \phi^{2n} &=& \frac{\phi^N - 1}{\phi^2 - 1} \\
&=& \frac{\phi^N - 1}{\phi} \\
&=& \phi^{N-1} - \phi + 1
\end{array}

The above steps follow from the properties of the golden ratio. But clearly this can't be. Would someone please pinpoint the error in my line of thought?

Comment: *But clearly this can't be* - Well, “clearly”, it *can*. :-)

Comment: *Would someone please pinpoint the error in my line of thought?* - The only error in your line of thought is not believing in your own line of thought. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N (-\phi)^n = -\phi \frac{(-\phi)^N-1}{-\phi-1} = \frac{\phi^N-1}{\phi}
$$

Comment: Where did the $(-1)^N$ go?

Comment: OP: "$N$ is an even integer"

Comment: Oops. 9 more to go